# Symfony - Doctrine : Designing REST api for receiving Many To Many Entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

Imagine I have a two ORM Entities:

> Author Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(
 *        name="authors",
 *        uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="date", columns={"author_id"})}
 * )
 */
class Author implements \JsonSerializable
{

 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
public $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250, nullable=true)
 */
public $name;

/**
 *
 * Many Authors have Many Books.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Book")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="authors_books",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
public $books;


public function __construct(User $user, \DateTime $startDate, \DateTime $ringDate, $phone, $name, $direction, $duration, $comment, $phoneId, $appVersion)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->books = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

}

public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'books' => $this->books,
    ];
}
}
```

> Book Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="books")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Book implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=120, nullable=false)
     */
    public $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     */
    public $color;

    public function __construct($decription)
    {
        $this->$decription = $decription;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getdecription()
    {
        return $this->decription;
    }

    public function setDecription($decription)
    {
        $this->decription = $decription;
    }

    function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'decription' => $this->decription,
        ];
    }
}
```

As the result of this relation a authors_books table is generated.
My goal for now is to design a controller which would return a list of authors in the following `json format` example:

```
{
    authors: [
        {
            name: "Oscar Wilde",
            books : [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    description: "The Picture of Dorian Gray"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    description: "The Happy Prince and Other Tales"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Charles Dickens",
            books : [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    description: "Great Expectations"
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    description: "Oliver Twist"
                }
            ]
        }
        ]
}
```

Using rest controller such as this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/my/v1", service="app.authors_controller")
 */
class MyController extends BaseApiController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/authors", name="my_v1_authors")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function authors(Request $request)
    {

        $qb = $this->authorRepository->createQueryBuilder('c');

        return new JsonResponse(array(
            'authors' => ...
        ));
    }
}
```

As for now I have a two ideas of achieving that:

1. Performing two request: one for an array of authors and the other for an array of books.
2. Keeping json representation of an array of book entities as an additional authors table's column.

But both of them seem to me a bit hacky. What should I do?

Please note, that this is the simplified representation of what I am trying to achieve. Although employing Many to Many relations for this particular example may seem to be an overhead it is crucial for my current task.

Comment: Couldn't you write a custom repository function that grabs the authors, and the underlying book entities, and then configure a serialization method to return that data?

Comment: Check out JMS serializer. It can serialize the collection and all of the related objects/collections according to your configuration. jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you change your JsonSerialize in your Author entity

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    $author = [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'books' => []
    ];

    foreach($this->books as $book)
    {
        $author['books'][] = $book->jsonSerialize();
    }

    return $author;
}
```

and in your controller:

```
$authors = /** your optimized query here **/
$serializedAuthors = [];

foreach($authors as $author)
{
    $serializedAuthors[] = $author->jsonSerialize();
}
```

If you might reuse this logic alot, you could consider using the Serializer component from symfony, a great guide can be found here https://thomas.jarrand.fr/blog/serialization/

Or maybe use JMSSerializer.

**EDIT**

Your DQL could look something like the following:

```
$authors = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
    SELECT author, books
    FROM AppBundle\Entity\Author author
    JOIN author.books books
')->getResult();
```

Comment: I just don't see how this might work: I'm fetching using native sql query results for authors from `authors` table. Is it supposed that doctrine would fetch `books` for each corresponding `author` entity behind scenes?

Comment: Yes, or if you prefer to load it in one go, you could write custom DQL for that instead of a raw query. Check my edits

Comment: Thanks for your response, that is exactly what I was looking for!